# passing an array into get command in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to pass an array in the query string of an rspec test but it's giving me an error. I will be sending query strings like "products[]=desk,chair" and expect the controller to be able to handle it.

Here's the error:

```
Failure/Error: get :index, { :format => :json, :products => [product_1, product_2]}, { "Accept" => "application/json" }
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for "[\"desk\", \"chair\"]":String
```

Here's my test method:

```
product_1 = "desk"
product_2 = "chair"
get :index, { :format => :json, :products => [product_1, product_2]}, { "Accept" => "application/json" }
```

Heres my controller:

```
products.each do |product|
    puts "product: #{product}"
end

def products
    params[:products].to_s
end
```

Any ideas?

Note: this is running Rails 3.2.12

Comment: any ideas on how to fix this problem? I will be sending query strings like "products[]=desk,chair" and expect the controller to be able to handle it

Comment: Well, you are converting your params into a string so you have a string. You also should be sending `products[]=desk&products[]=chair` if you want an array.

Answer (score 4):

You are defining `products` as `params[:products].to_s` that makes it an string, no matter what you send. So when you do `products.each` in the `index` method it fails.

Do the each on `params[:products]` instead:

```
def index
  params[:products].each do |product|
    puts "product: #{product}"
  end
end
```

I'm sure that puts, is  just troubleshooting code, but you shouldn't use it on your controller.

Comment: awesome! thank you! can't believe I missed that one haha